# Tracking Changes and Development for Embedded Linux

Tags: embedded, buildroot, version-control

I'm starting to develop on an embedded linux system and am trying to figure out what the best way to manage my work is. Currently I'm using buildroot to build an image based on the vendors defconfig, but I'd like to build on this by make changes to the kernel, customizing u-boot, writing drivers, adding applications, etc.

What's the best way to manage this workflow? Should I fork the kernel, uboot, etc and track all my changes in my own git repo? Just track the files I change? Work entirely with patches?

Comment: Check out the [Yocto project](https://www.yoctoproject.org/) (which uses [OpenEmbedded](http://www.openembedded.org/)) ... steep learning curve but not a bad way to do embedded linux.